# get the result from the FileReader()

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, filereader

I have the following problem.

I have an upload form for multiple files. The upload process goes fine. The problem is related with the FileReader() result. As I am uploading multiple files(images) I need to create corresponding thumbs when the upload is finished.

```
files = e.target.files;

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

    //ajax request goes here

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function (e) {

        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.file = e;
        img.className = 'thumbs_';
        img.src = e.target.result;

        //Every image has a wrapper div with the id 'nDv0','nDv1','nDv2' etc.                   

        document.getElementById('nDv' + i).appendChild(img);
    })(e);

    reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);

    //request sent

}
```

If I remove the closures around the anonymous function, i's value will be anything when the for loop exits. 
For example, if there are 3 files, i's value will be 3 and the results will be appended to the last wrapper div and images will be displayed.

With closures every image is getting appended to the corresponding div, but the images won't be displayed as the returned result is undefined.

So, how can I append every thumb to its corresponding div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You has a `logic error`:

```
reader.onload = (function (e) {
    //onload code
    //inside function e is event from outside
})(e);//e is event from upper code
```

And the `i` will be equal to `files.length` because `onload` handler is async.
So you must change your `onload` handler to:

```
reader.onload = function (index) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.className = 'thumbs_';//it's right className?
    img.src = this.result;//result is dataURL                
    document.getElementById('nDv' + index).appendChild(img);
}.bind(reader, i);
```

Comment: Thank's for clearing that out.
I've tried removing closures, but doing so i gets the last value when the for loop exits.
Btw, I've already removed img.file line

Comment: Yes, i will be equal to files.length because onload handler is async. Try again onload handler from my edit answer.

Comment: It works, but the img.src is now null. No image is displayed.

Comment: Oh. Sorry I test code in fiddle and fix errors. Now all works. I manipulate by function context and arguments by `bind`, but it must available when `FileReader` works.

Comment: It's [native](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method.